# android edit sharedpreferences existing variable called zipcode

Tags: android

I have my code:

```
final EditText input2 = new EditText(mActivity);


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
                    builder.setTitle("User Info Request:");
                    builder.setMessage("Enter Zip Code:");

                    final EditText input2 = new EditText(mActivity);

                   builder.setView(input2);

                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                   editor.putString("zipcode","input2");
                   editor.commit();


}
```

How can i take that string/text the user entered and replace my shared preferences value 'zipcode' with the value Input2 ? The way i try now it sets the "zipcode" shared pref to "input2" but i need the result of user input to change the existing value in shared prefs... =/

I have made several attempts at this with no luck, and help would be great.

Droidster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
editor.putString("zipcode", input2.getText().toString());
```

You received the error because, as it says, you can't put an edit text into the putString method; it needs to be of type String.

Also, I don't see where you have your buttons.

Try this:

```
buider.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("zipcode", input2.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
```

That way when the user is done typing and they hit the ok button, then, it will get the text the user entered

Comment: No error, but value was empty when i checked after inputing value in alert dialog box.. =?